# Sort Firefox Bookmarks by Domain

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, bookmarks

Is there a way to sort bookmarks by domain? I would like to be able to see all youtube vidoes in one section, all wikipedia in another, etc, but I haven't been able to find an add-on that does this. If there is a menu I've overlooked or an about:config tweak please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [addon to do this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-sort-bookmarks/)

But if you want to sort just for temporarily, then in the *Show All Bookmarks* window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) you can change the sort order without addons. (Click on the *Views* field)